# Parsing through a text file and skipping lines with Powershell

Tags: powershell, text

I have a massive text file that looks like the following:

```
------
Device Location: Seattle
Entry address(es):
IP address: 10.0.0.1
----------
Device Location: New York
Entry address(es):
IP address: 10.5.0.1
----------
Device Location: Las Vegas
Entry address(es):
IP address: 10.9.0.1
----------
Device Location: Seattle
Entry address(es):
IP address: 10.0.6.1
----------
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the IP addresses for all devices in Seattle. I'm using a foreach loop to parse through the text and find any string that has "Seattle" but once I find Seattle I don't know how to grab the IP address that is 2 lines underneath it.

Does anyone know what the solution is here?

```
$text = get-content textfile.txt
foreach($line in $text){
            if ($line -match "Seattle"){
               skip 1 line and grab IP
}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You read the next line and discard (ignore) it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet with its `-Context` parameter to find lines containing the string `Seattle` and capture the next two lines as well.

You can then extract the IP address from the 2nd line following each match, as follows:

```bash
Select-String -Context 0, 2 -Pattern Seattle -LiteralPath textfile.txt |
  ForEach-Object { (-split $_.Context.PostContext[-1])[-1] }
```